# Using text annotations with plotly::subplot

Tags: r, annotations, plotly, subplot

I have data I'd like to plot the distribution density of. The data are from three groups, where for each there are three states, each with a probability, and these probabilities sum to 1.

I'm trying to use `R`'s `plotly` to plot, for each group, the density of the probabilities, color coded by state, and add some text `annotation` to each such group plot. Finally I'm trying to combine all of these group plots using `plotly::subplot`.

Here's the code to generate the data and a `list` of group plots:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(plotly)

set.seed(1)

plot.list <- lapply(1:3,function(g){
  if(g == 1){
    show.legend <- T
  } else{
    show.legend <- F
  }
  df <- data.frame(id=LETTERS,t(sapply(1:length(LETTERS),function(x){
    probs <- runif(3,0,1)
    return(probs/sum(probs))
  }))) %>% dplyr::rename(S1=X1,S2=X2,S3=X3) %>%
    reshape2::melt() %>% dplyr::rename(state=variable,probability=value)
  df$state <- factor(df$state,levels=c("S1","S2","S3"))
  density.df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(levels(df$state),function(s){
    dens <- density(dplyr::filter(df,state == s)$probability)
    return(data.frame(x=dens$x,y=dens$y,state=s,stringsAsFactors=F))
  }))
  density.df$state <- factor(density.df$state,levels=levels(df$state))
  dens.plot <- plot_ly(x=~density.df$x,y=~density.df$y,type='scatter',mode='lines',color=~density.df$state,showlegend=show.legend) %>%
    layout(xaxis=list(title="Probability",zeroline=F),yaxis=list(title="Count",zeroline=F)) %>%
    add_annotations(x=0.75,y="top",text=paste0("text: ",g))
  if(show.legend) dens.plot <- dens.plot %>% add_annotations(text="State",xref="paper",yref="paper",x=1.02,xanchor="left",y=1.02,yanchor="top",legendtitle=T,showarrow=F)
  return(dens.plot)
})
```

Note that I'm only adding the `legend` to the first group so it appears only once in the final grouped plot (there's probably a more elegant way of achieving that).

And here's the `plotly::subplot` command I'm using:

```
subplot(plot.list,nrows=3,shareX=T,shareY=T,titleX=T,titleY=T)
```

Which gives:

[image]

As you can see the text `annotation` is stuck at "top" of the first plot rather than at the top of each individual plot.

Any idea how do I get each `annotation` to be located at the top of its corresponding sub-plot?

Answer (score 3):

**Preamble.** For reasons that are not entirely obvious to me (but relating to how values for annotations are scaled when running `subplot`), annotations seem to go awry with vertically stacked subplots. To see this, run the MWE at https://plot.ly/r/text-and-annotations/#subplot-annotations, but change

```
subplot(p1, p2, titleX = TRUE, titleY = TRUE)
```

to

```
subplot(p1, p2, titleX = TRUE, titleY = TRUE, nrows = 2)
```

In the vertically stacked version, the annotations are not where we would expect them to be.  To achieve your desired outcome would require some post-processing of the `subplot` output.  Now, on to your main question.

---

First, in `add_annotations`, add `xref` and `yref` arguments that correspond to each `subplot`.  In each element of `plot.list`, I also add an additional element `y_anno` to keep track of where we would like the annotation to go (at the maximum value of the densities in each subplot).

```
plot.list <- lapply(1:3,function(g){
  if(g == 1){
    show.legend <- T
  } else{
    show.legend <- F
  }
  df <- data.frame(id=LETTERS,t(sapply(1:length(LETTERS),function(x){
    probs <- runif(3,0,1)
    return(probs/sum(probs))
  }))) %>% dplyr::rename(S1=X1,S2=X2,S3=X3) %>%
    reshape2::melt() %>% dplyr::rename(state=variable,probability=value)
  df$state <- factor(df$state,levels=c("S1","S2","S3"))
  density.df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(levels(df$state),function(s){
    dens <- density(dplyr::filter(df,state == s)$probability)
    return(data.frame(x=dens$x,y=dens$y,state=s,stringsAsFactors=F))
  }))
  density.df$state <- factor(density.df$state,levels=levels(df$state))
  dens.plot <- plot_ly(x=~density.df$x,
                       y=~density.df$y,
                       type='scatter',
                       mode='lines',
                       color=~density.df$state,
                       showlegend=show.legend) %>%
    layout(xaxis=list(title="Probability",zeroline=F),yaxis=list(title="Count",zeroline=F)) %>%
    add_annotations(x = 0.75,
                    y = max(density.df$y),
                    text = paste0("text: ", g),
                    xref = paste0("x", g),  # add this
                    yref = paste0("y", g),  # add this
                    ax = 0,
                    ay = 0)
  if(show.legend) dens.plot <- dens.plot %>% add_annotations(text="State",xref="paper",yref="paper",x=1.02,xanchor="left",y=1.02,yanchor="top",legendtitle=T,showarrow=F)
  dens.plot$y_anno <- max(density.df$y)  # add this
  return(dens.plot)
})
```

Now if we run `subplot(plot.list,nrows=3,shareX=T,shareY=T,titleX=T,titleY=T)`, the text will be in each subplot, but not at the top (due to the phenomenon I described in the preamble). To fix this, we can post-process the `subplot` output:

```
p <- subplot(plot.list, nrows = 3,shareX = T,shareY = T,titleX = T,titleY = T)
for (i in seq_along(plot.list)) {
  for (j in seq_along(p$x$layout$annotations)) {
    if (p$x$layout$annotations[[j]]$yref == paste0("y", i))
      p$x$layout$annotations[[j]]$y <- plot.list[[i]]$y_anno
  }
}
```

Now `p` gives us

[image]

which is close to what we want.

Comment: I'm not getting the output you're getting. Looks like the `xref` and `yref` arguments in the `add_annotations` call are messing up `plot.list[[2]]` and `plot.list[[3]]`